# How to move powers from denominator into numuerator? $\frac{x^n}{1+x^m}=\frac{x^{\frac{n-m+1}m}}{m(1+x)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, fractions

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216/595084), robjohn simplifies $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{1+x^m}\mathrm{d}x
=\frac1m\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{\frac{n-m+1}m}}{1+x}\mathrm{d}x$$
How do you go about this shuffling of powers into the numerator?

I've tried multiple factoring strategies such as factoring the bottom into $$x-e^{i\pi(2k+1)/3},\quad k=0,1,...,n-1$$ as well as attempting to simplify the end result back into the first, but to no avail.

A step by step demonstration would be really appreciated!

Comment: It's not a direct manipulation of the integrand. It's a u-substitution $x\rightarrow x^{1/m}$.

Comment: Substitution $y=x^m$, then re-name the dummy variable $y$ back to $x$.

Comment: Oh bruh. That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Substitution $y=x^m$, then re-name the dummy variable y back to x.

as per GEdgar's comment